# Shared memory - matrix mapping

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory

I'm currently working on a Bomberman game project where there should be a Server, which has a bidimensional matrix, and 1 or more Clients.

The way that I think it should be done is by using shared memory between process, where the clients and "enemies" access to get the information about the Table Map(Matrix) and work with that.

The problem is that I don't know how to map a pointer to my Map object(Matrix) so the other processes can grab that information.

I've got this function from MSDN but I only explain to a string:

```
   //Server.cpp

   //object creation (Matrix)
   Mapa M(height, width);

  hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
             INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
             NULL,                    // default security
             PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
             0,                       // maximum object size(high-order DWORD)
             BUF_SIZE,               // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
             szName);                // name of mapping object

if (hMapFile == NULL)
{
     _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
      GetLastError());

  return 1;
}

**HANDLE hMapFile = &M; // will this work?**

pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // <- How can I pass the object here?
                    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
                    0,
                    0,
                    BUF_SIZE);

if (pBuf == NULL)
{
       _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
       GetLastError());

   CloseHandle(hMapFile);

  return 1;
```

}

Please how can I map a pointer to an object or even to an object so the other processes can access?

Regards,

RC

Comment: `CreateFileMapping` is only one step on accessing a shared memory, the other one being [`MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but how can i point my matrix object?

Comment: This design will limit your client and server to running on the same machine. Generally a client and server would be running on separate boxes and communicating via TCP/IP. Why are you using shared memory?

Comment: You don't point the memory to your matrix object. You are given some memory, in which you write your matrix in. But as StilesCrisis has mentioned, this isn't a good idea for implementing multiplayer.

Comment: @StilesCrisis They will interact over named pipes. Therefore they will be able to run over the same network.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo  So how will i make the data inside de matrix accessible over the clients?

Comment: Named pipes and shared memory can't be accessed over a network, even with a networked file system.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo So, my Server is going to create a matrix, mapping it on memory, wait for clients to connect and then, for each one create a Thread to listen they command requests separately over named pipes. Doesn't this going to work?

Comment: As Stiles has said, it will only work on the same machine. Other machines won't be able to access the server's memory or filesystem, and I doubt networked filesystems implement memory mapping or pipes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77943/discussion-between-ricardo-costa-and-colonel-thirty-two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a mapping file your server code should look something like the following. Note that I do not check for any errors to keep the posted code simple (always check for errors!).

```
/* server */
HANDLE hFile;
HANDLE hMapFile;

hFile = CreateFile("test.dat",
                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                   0,
                   NULL,
                   OPEN_EXISTING,
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                   NULL);
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile,
                             NULL,
                             PAGE_READWRITE,
                             0,
                             1024 * 1024,
                             "test.mapping");   // "mapping file name" of "test.dat"

/* keep server process running and do not close hFile or hMapFile */
```

And your client should look something like this:

```
/* client */
HANDLE hMapFile;
char *pFile;   // note: you can use any type of pointer here!

hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE,
                           FALSE,
                           "test.mapping");   // same name as within CreateFileMapping(..)
if (hMapFile != NULL)
{
    pFile = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,
                          FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
                          0,
                          0,
                          1024 * 1024);

    /* read pFile */
    printf(pFile);

    /* write pFile */        
    wsprintf(pFile, "Hallo?");   // <-- writes to test.dat!!
}
```

As noted before this design will have some drawbacks if used for a server/client architecture. I recommend using a TCP/IP server/client which is no more difficult to implement than named pipes. A good place to start would be [Running the Winsock Client and Server Code Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but there are numerous other examples on the web...

If using TCP/IP your application will look something like this:

```
/* server */

// create listener socket

// while running

   // accept new client(s)

   // receive data from clients (if any data was received)

   // react on data: (client sent 0x01 -> send matrix, ...)



/* client */

// create socket and connect to server

// send 0x01 command to obtain matrix

// receive response from server (= get matrix)

// do whatever your client does...
```

Note that the `0x01` is a simple command byte to tell the server what to do. You're completely free on how to tell the server what to do. You can as well implement a string based command interface (e.g. client sends "get_matrix" instead of 0x01)...